# Lexical or Preprocessor Issue - Regarding FacebookSDK, Cordova 2.5.0, & Facebook Plugin

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, cordova

I followed the instructions here (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin) to set-up a Facebook connection using a Phonegap app. However, I never could successfully get the project to build after doing everything I was told.

At one point I attempted to fix the issue by removing my Framework Search Paths (which are now empty) and now I've tried referencing the header in "User Header Search Paths" like this ("$(SRCROOT)/../../FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FacebookSDK.h") but I've still had no luck.

What do I need to do to get this project to build? I've tried cleaning then building, and restarting Xcode, but still no luck. I have "Always Search User Paths" set to yes.

Running Xcode 4.6, Cordova 2.5.0, the newest Facebook plugin, and Facebook SDK 3.5.1

Error screenshot here: http://imgur.com/6MTaLOQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I figured it out. The issue was duplicate references in the Facebook Phonegap plugin.